# Most pythonic way to get the previous element

Tags: python, iterator

I would like an `enumerate`-like functional on iterators which yields the pair `(previous_element, current_element)`.  That is, given that `iter` is

```
i0, i1, i1, ...
```

I would like `offset(iter)` to yield

```
(None, i0), (i0, i1), (i1, i2) ...
```

Comment: There isn't a "most pythonic" way. You are going to see "more pythonic" ways (e.g., using a function rather than a class with two factory classes to create the first class), but "pythonic" is a subjective idea.

Comment: Click the ✓ below one of the answers to accept it.

Answer (score 26):

What about the simple (obvious) solution?

```
def offset(iterable):
    prev = None
    for elem in iterable:
        yield prev, elem
        prev = elem
```

Comment: Looks good to me, reckon I've got something very similar in a very repository near by.

Comment: I don't know why everyone's jumping all over `itertools` for this.  Why use a sledgehammer and railroad spike when a pushpin will do?

Comment: But `itertools` is the mystical silver bullet that solves everything!

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Better do it yourself than wasting time searching and asking.

Comment: @xiaomao -- agreed (partly).  When there's a library function to do what you want, use it.  It'll work as good as or better than anything you could come up with.  However, readability counts.  As soon as your function becomes difficult to read/decipher, you should probably think about simplifying it :).

Answer (score 8):

To put more itertools on the table:

```
from itertools import tee, izip, chain

def tee_zip(iterable):
   a, b = tee(iterable)
   return izip(chain([None], a), b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    """s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ...
    see http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html
    """
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    b.next()
    return itertools.izip(a, b)
```

**EDIT** moved doc string into the function

Comment: Doesn't give you `(None,i0)` for the first pair

Comment: @MattH Easy to fix; change the `b.next()` line to `yield (None, b.next())` (and then loop over the `izip` and yield, or use the Python 3.3 `yield from` syntax).

Comment: @MattH, yeah, I know. I suppose OP will be able to work out the details. This code is from the docs and is considered to be a hint for the problem on hand.

Comment: Just a note, your docstring should go *after* your function declaration (indented appropriately).  This *will* work, but you're basically creating a string just to throw it away again and this makes triple quoted strings look like some form of block comment (syntactically they're not the same thing even though your program will behave the same in *some* circumstances).

Comment: @mgilson, since August I have already learned that. Still, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
def offset(iter, n=1, pad=None):
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(iter)
    i1_padded = itertools.chain(itertools.repeat(pad, n), i1)
    return itertools.izip(i1_padded, i2)
```

@bpgergo + @user792036 = this. Best of two worlds :).

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have (and this requires `itertools`) is

```
def offset(iter, n=1):
    # returns tuples (None, iter0), (iter0, iter1), (iter1, iter2) ...
    previous = chain([None] * n, iter)
    return izip(previous, iter)
```

but I would be interested in seeing if someone has a one-liner (or a better name than offset for this function)!

Comment: This doesn't work properly on iterators (as opposed to iterables). For example: `list(offset(i for i in xrange(10)))` returns
`[(None, 0), (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]`.

Comment: The general idea is good here, you just need to make 2 independent iterators over the given iterator using `tee`. See my answer.