# Pythonic iteration over sliding window pairs in list?

Tags: python, list, iteration, python-itertools, list-manipulation

What's the most Pythonic efficient way to iterate over a list in sliding pairs? Here's a related example:

```
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> for x, y in itertools.izip(l, l[1::2]): print x, y
... 
a b
b d
c f
```

this is iteration in pairs, but how can we get iteration over a sliding pair? Meaning iteration over the pairs:

```
a b
b c
c d
d e
etc.
```

which is iteration over the pairs, except sliding the pair by 1 element each time rather than by 2 elements. thanks.

Comment: *Very* closely related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076270/most-pythonic-way-to-get-the-previous-element/12076386#12076386

Comment: Yep, the only difference is that in the other question they wanted the very first pair to have `None` at position 0.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa -- Yeah, which is why I didn't mark this as a dupe.  But I think that the general ideas still apply in the various answers there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
for x, y in itertools.izip(l, l[1:]): print x, y
```

Comment: Python 3 doesn't have `izip` but does have `zip_longest`. To avoid having an empty spot in the last pair, I used `for x, y in itertools.zip_longest(l[:-1], l[1:]): print x, y`.

Comment: @jtpereyda, Python 3 has the top-level function `zip`, which does the same thing as `itertools.izip`. If you don't want an empty spot in the last pair, you can use @chmullig's answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can go even simpler. Just zip the list and the list offset by one.

```
In [4]: zip(l, l[1:])
Out[4]: [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('e', 'f'), ('f', 'g')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little generator that I wrote a while back for a similar scenario:

```
def pairs(items):
    items_iter = iter(items)
    prev = next(items_iter)

    for item in items_iter:
        yield prev, item
        prev = item
```

Comment: This is basically the iterator protocol, except written as a generator.  Why not just make this a custom iterator class (something like `PairsIter`)?

Comment: @sr2222 -- You could do that, but why?  Though I haven't done any tests, I sort of doubt the class would be much faster, and the generator is quite simple.

Comment: This is what I would do (+1) -- Although, I might avoid using a non-descriptive variable `i`.  Instead I might call it `items_iter` or something to that effect -- While this does cost an extra 18 bytes of disk space, I think it's well worth it for the clarity :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a function for arbitrarily sized sliding windows that works for iterators/generators as well as lists

```
def sliding(seq, n):
  return izip(*starmap(islice, izip(tee(seq, n), count(0), repeat(None))))
```

Nathan's solution is probably more efficient though.

Answer (score 1):

The timing, as defined by the addition of two subsequent entries in the list, is displayed below and ordered from fastest to slowest.

Gil

```
In [69]: timeit.repeat("for x,y in itertools.izip(l, l[1::1]): x + y", setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[69]: [1.029047966003418, 0.996290922164917, 0.998831033706665]
```

Geoff Reedy

```
In [70]: timeit.repeat("for x,y in sliding(l,2): x+y", setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[70]: [1.2408790588378906, 1.2099130153656006, 1.207326889038086]
```

Alestanis

```
In [66]: timeit.repeat("for i in range(0, len(l)-1): l[i] + l[i+1]", setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[66]: [1.3387370109558105, 1.3243639469146729, 1.3245630264282227]
```

chmullig

```
In [68]: timeit.repeat("for x,y in zip(l, l[1:]): x+y", setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[68]: [1.4756009578704834, 1.4369518756866455, 1.5067830085754395]
```

Nathan Villaescusa

```
In [63]: timeit.repeat("for x,y in pairs(l): x+y", setup=setup, number=1000)
Out[63]: [2.254757881164551, 2.3750967979431152, 2.302199125289917]
```

sr2222

Notice the reduced repetition number...

```
In [60]: timeit.repeat("for x,y in SubsequenceIter(l,2): x+y", setup=setup, number=100)
Out[60]: [1.599524974822998, 1.5634570121765137, 1.608154058456421]
```

The setup code:

```
setup="""
from itertools import izip, starmap, islice, tee, count, repeat
l = range(10000)

def sliding(seq, n):
  return izip(*starmap(islice, izip(tee(seq, n), count(0), repeat(None))))

class SubsequenceIter(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable, subsequence_length):

        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.subsequence_length = subsequence_length
        self.subsequence = [0]

    def __iter__(self):

        return self

    def next(self):

        self.subsequence.pop(0)
        while len(self.subsequence) < self.subsequence_length:
            self.subsequence.append(self.iterator.next())
        return self.subsequence

def pairs(items):
    items_iter = iter(items)
    prev = items_iter.next()

    for item in items_iter:
        yield (prev, item)
        prev = item
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the most efficient, but quite flexible:

```
class SubsequenceIter(object):

    def __init__(self, iterable, subsequence_length):

        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.subsequence_length = subsequence_length
        self.subsequence = [0]

    def __iter__(self):

        return self

    def next(self):

        self.subsequence.pop(0)
        while len(self.subsequence) < self.subsequence_length:
            self.subsequence.append(self.iterator.next())
        return self.subsequence
```

Usage:

```
for x, y in SubsequenceIter(l, 2):
    print x, y
```

Comment: This requires that the iterable be sliceable -- It wont work with general iterators.

Answer (score 0):

No need for imports, this will work provided a list of objects or a string; anything with `var[indexing]`. Tested on `python 3.6`

```
# This will create windows with all but 1 overlap
def ngrams_list(a_list, window_size=5, skip_step=1):
    return list(zip(*[a_list[i:] for i in range(0, window_size, skip_step)]))
```

the for loop by itself creates this with `a_list` being the alphabet (shown `window = 5`, OP would want `window=2`:

```
['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
 'BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
 'CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
 'DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
 'EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

`zip(*result_of_for_loop)` will collect all full vertical columns as results. And if you want less than all-but-one overlap:

```
# You can sample that output to get less overlap:
def sliding_windows_with_overlap(a_list, window_size=5, overlap=2):
    zip_output_as_list = ngrams_list(a_list, window_size)])
    return zip_output_as_list[::overlap+1]
```

With `overlap=2` it skips the columns starting with `B`& `C`, and choosing the `D`

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'),
 ('D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'), 
 ('G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'), 
 ('J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N'), 
 ('M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q'), 
 ('P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'), 
 ('S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W'), 
 ('V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z')]
```

EDIT: looks like this is similar to what @chmullig provided, with options