# Going over a list of times paired with a string and finding out if one time is on a different day to another

Tags: python, date, loops, web, web.py

I wasn't very clear on how to express what I meant in the title, I think I can explain it better here.

I have a list (entries) which consists of this:

```
1358345153|russelg|[add] changelog @ /changelog
1358339500|russelg|ajaxify image uploads
```

The first value is a unix timestamp. Now, since this is for a changelog-type thing, I'd like to place a `<span>` (or similar) between two different days.

My code currently is:

```
for e in entries:
    ez = e.split('|')
    epoch = ez[0]
    auth = ez[1]
    type = 'fix'
    ext = '.png'
    message = ez[2]
    if re.match('\[(.+?)\]', message):
        type = re.findall('\[(.+?)\]', message)[0]
    message = re.sub('\[(.+?)\]', '', message)
    ledate = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch))
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(epoch)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d @ %H:%M:%S')
```

Then I print this out as a html string.

```
<div class="changelog-text">
    <span class="epoch">2013-01-17 @ 00:05:53</span> 
    <span class="type">add</span> 
    [<span class="auth"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/russelg">russelg</a></span>]  
    changelog @ /changelog
</div>
```

The thing that puzzles me is how to compare two different dates in the for loop.

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, something like this might be helpful ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076270/most-pythonic-way-to-get-the-previous-element/12076386#12076386

Answer (score 0):

> The thing that puzzles me is how to compare two different dates in the for loop.

You're already building a `datetime` object from the timestamp. You can have the date alone by getting the `datetime.date` object.

```
this_entry_date = ledate.date()
```

Now you could very well organize your code to keep reference of the `datetime.date` of the previous entry and run a regular comparison between that and the current entry's date. Along the lines of:

```
if this_entry_date > last_entry_date:
    output_span()
```

[Python: datetime.date](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date)